# Java retrieve value from TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, Integer>>

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I'm pretty new to Maps and I'm quite stuck. I have the following TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String, Map<String, Integer>> routes = new TreeMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
```

Let's say, for example, my TreeMap is filled as follows:

```
{A={B=10, C=15, D=20}, B={C=35, D=25}, D={C=30}}
```

Now I'm trying to print out the Integer value from my TreeMap and assign it to an `int x = routes.get(0).get(0)` but I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

After a bit of reading, I understood that I'm trying to cast an String object into an Integer object which is not correct and that’s why Java throws the error meaning my `x` is being assigned to `B` and not `10`.

So my question is how do I assign x to the value of 10?

Comment: I find this strange.  Normally [`.get` would return `null`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)) if the key didn't exist (or happened to map to `null`), and you'd get a NullPointerException instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.get()` is attempting to use the key of the map that you've declared.  Since you want to find the value within Map[A][B], then you should refer to it as such:

```
int x = routes.get("A").get("B");
```

Comment: I'm using it in a loop so I can make an adjacency matrix based on those values. So I cannot use "A" or "B" but have to use i or j which are integers(from my nested for loops)

Comment: I think your design's wrong, then.  You're mapping `String` to `String` to `int`; you have *no other way* to get through the mapping with anything other than `String`s.

Comment: What would be a better way to make it?

Comment: That's a broader question than what you've phrased here, I'm afraid.  Although, if you're looking for hints on adjacency matrices, then you should search this site.  There are a lot of approaches to it in Java.

Comment: I edited the question a bit, but thanks anyways. I'll look into it.

Comment: What I meant by "broader question" is that it should be asked as an entirely different question if you don't find any questions here to answer it.  Editing it into your question runs the risk of invalidating existing answers.